# Qgis 3.0 and Qt 5.10 problems

Tags: qgis, qt

I installed Girona on Ubuntu 17.10 and it never worked for me.
I just updated Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Qgis displays the following message:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, inImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.10 'not found (required by / home / user / .local / lib / python3.6 / site-packages / PyQt5 / QtCore.so)

And it does not connect to the plugin repository.

Comment: Did you go to the file paths mentioned in the message to make sure you have the necessary files?

Comment: Yes, those files are on the routes mentioned

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290448/unable-to-compile-qgis-3-x-master-on-ubuntu-16-04-pyqt5-pyqtconfig-module-doe/292614?noredirect=1#comment469647_292614 . Don't use self-compiled versions of PyQt5, but only the Ubuntu repo version.