# Compiling QGIS 3.x (master) on Ubuntu 16.04 with Python3.6 and the latest Qt 5 and PyQt5 familiy modules (PyQt5, sip, qscintilla, pyqtchart)

Tags: qt, python-3, compile, pyqt5, qgis-3

### The problem:

Now that the compilation issue is over ([Unable to compile QGIS 3.x (master) on Ubuntu 16.04: PyQt5.pyqtconfig module does not exist](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290448/unable-to-compile-qgis-3-x-master-on-ubuntu-16-04-pyqt5-pyqtconfig-module-doe)), **QGIS 3** (master) **refuses to load Python at startup**.
I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 (4.15.0-30-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux).
- `Python3` version is `3.5.2`
- `PyQt5` is `5.10.1`
- `SIP` is `4.19.12` (manually installed, detected version during the compilation is `4.19.12`, but sip.SIP_VERSION_STR when imported directly in a python3.5 console is `4.19.8`. I cannot understand why)
- `QScintilla` is `2.10.4`
These packages have been dowgraded as explained here: [Unable to compile QGIS 3.x (master) on Ubuntu 16.04: PyQt5.pyqtconfig module does not exist](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290448/unable-to-compile-qgis-3-x-master-on-ubuntu-16-04-pyqt5-pyqtconfig-module-doe/292614#292614)

Here is the error message I am facing in a popup window during QGIS 3 startup:

```
Couldn't load PyQt.
Python support will be disabled.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so)


Python version:
3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

QGIS version:
3.3.0-Master 'Master', ad4ddb1
```

Followed by a second popup window:

```
An error occurred during execution of following code:
qgis.utils.uninstallErrorHook()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'qgis' is not defined


Python version:
3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

QGIS version:
3.3.0-Master 'Master', ad4ddb1
```

Then QGIS is ready to use, but there is no Python console (which I really need).

### Second try; updating Python3 from `3.5.2` to `3.6.5`:

Then I though it was a Python related issue, so I decided to install Python `3.6.5` (from this PPA: http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu) in parallel to the default system Python `3.5.2` in Ubuntu 16.04.
So I changed the PYTHON_EXECUTABLE, PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR and PYTHON_LIBRARY to version 3.6 instead of 3.5.
I also made a `pip3.6` command in order to install packages for this version of Python and I installed, this time the latest version of the PyQt5 serie:
- `PyQt5` version: `5.11.2`
- `SIP` version: `4.19.12`
- `QScintilla2` PyQt module: `2.10.7`

At QGIS startup, the same two popup windows appeared:

```
Couldn't load PyQt.
Python support will be disabled.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.11' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so)

Python version:
3.6.5 (default, May  3 2018, 10:08:28) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

QGIS version:
3.3.0-Master 'Master', ad4ddb1
```

Followed by:

```
An error occurred during execution of following code:
qgis.utils.uninstallErrorHook()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'qgis' is not defined


Python version:
3.6.5 (default, May  3 2018, 10:08:28) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

QGIS version:
3.3.0-Master 'Master', ad4ddb1
```

### What I realized at this point:

is that I was using the Qt5 I installed from the Ubuntu repositories, which version is `Qt 5.5.1`.
That's probably why QGIS cannot find the `Qt_5.10' string the first try and the`Qt_5.11' string in the second try. It probably wants the system Qt version to be the same than the PyQt module, in the first case PyQt was `5.10.1` and in the second `5.11.2`. So I assume they should be like a family and share the same version numbers (at least up to the minor digit).
I looked after 'how to install Qt 5.10 or Qt 5.11 on Ubuntu 16.04 and foud these PPA:
 - http://ppa.launchpad.net/beineri/opt-qt-5.10.1-xenial/ubuntu
 - http://ppa.launchpad.net/beineri/opt-qt-5.11.1-xenial/ubuntu

I added them both, installed Qt5.10 and Qt5.11 in `/opt` as described on the respective web pages from the PPAs and changed all the Qt5 variable path in cmake to the ones in '/opt/qt51x/lib/cmake/' + the QT_LRELEASE_EXECUTABLE variable to '/opt/qt51x/bin/lrelease' with x in [0 when building QGIS with Python3.5 and x=1 when building with Python3.6].

But then...

### New issue:

The configuration and generation is all OK, but the build outputs a lot (!) of C++ errors. I don't want to print them all but it looks like that:

https://pastebin.com/vZ20XPxv

### So, to summarize:

Either QGIS compile well with a PyQt 5.11.2 and system Qt 5.5.1 but refuses to load the Python console at startup telling that it cannot find `Qt_5.11' in  '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so
or QGIS doesn't compile when PyQt and Qt version are the same (up to the minor digit).

Comment: AndreJ suggested to stuck to the system Qt/PyQt version, namely `5.5.1`:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290448/unable-to-compile-qgis-3-x-master-on-ubuntu-16-04-pyqt5-pyqtconfig-module-doe/292614?noredirect=1#comment469654_292614

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on AndreJ comment, I uninstall all PyQt5 related packages with `pip3.5` (namely `pyqt5`, `sip`, `qscintilla` and `pyqtchart`) and used the official ones from my Ubuntu distribution.

Here is the cmake log which looks fine:

```
QGIS version: 3.3.0 Master (30300)
Could not find GRASS 7
Found Proj: /usr/local/lib/libproj.so (5.2.0)
Found GEOS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeos_c.so (3.5.0)
Found GDAL: /usr/local/lib/libgdal.so (2.3.1)
Found Expat: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so
Found Spatialindex: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspatialindex.so
Found Qwt: /usr/lib/libqwt-qt5.so (6.1.2)
Found libzip: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip.so
Found Sqlite3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so
Found PostgreSQL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so
Found SpatiaLite: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspatialite.so
Qt WebKit support DISABLED.
Found Qt version: 5.5.1
Found QScintilla2: /usr/lib/libqt5scintilla2.so (2.9.1)
Found QtKeychain: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqt5keychain.so
Found QCA: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqca-qt5.so (2.1.1)
Found QCA OpenSSL plugin
Pedantic compiler settings enabled
Found Python executable: /usr/bin/python3
Found Python version: 3.5.2
Found Python library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so
Found Python site-packages: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Found PyQt5 version: 5.5.1
Found SIP version: 4.17
Found QScintilla2 PyQt module: 2.9.1
Found GSL: -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
Ctest Binary Directory set to: /opt/QGIS/build_master/output/bin
Configuring done
Generating done
```

(Note: one has to deactivate QtWebKit because it was deprecated since Qt>=5.5)

And here is an error during the compilation:

```
[ 30%] Generating core/sip_corepart0.cpp, core/sip_corepart1.cpp, core/sip_corepart2.cpp, core/sip_corepart3.cpp
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/sip: not found
python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis__core.dir/build.make:515: recipe for target 'python/core/sip_corepart0.cpp' failed
make[2]: *** [python/core/sip_corepart0.cpp] Error 127
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'python/core/sip_corepart0.cpp'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4078: recipe for target 'python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis__core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis__core.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems that `cmake` can find `sip` during the configuration step but the compilation step with `make` does not. And I do not have any `/usr/bin/sip` on my system even after reinstalling `python3-sip` and `python3-sip-dev` packages with `apt`.

#### Parenthesis:

If you run into a `sipconfig` error or a:

```
CMake Error at cmake/FindSIP.cmake:54 (MESSAGE):
  Could not find SIP
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:753 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

after having `pip3.5` uninstalled a latest `sip` package and if you already have the system sip (`python3-sip` `python3-sip-dev`) just force the reinstallation of the later:

```
$ apt-get install python3-sip python3-sip-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-sip is already the newest version (4.17+dfsg-1build1).
python3-sip-dev is already the newest version (4.17+dfsg-1build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ apt-get install --reinstall python3-sip python3-sip-dev
```

Then cmake will find it.

### Identified problem:

There is two files in the QGIS sources `cmake/` folder:
 - FindSIP.cmake
 - FindSIP.py

the later beeing called by the former.

In the python file, one can read at line:39:

```
print("sip_bin:%s" % sipcfg.sip_bin)
```

this line prints:

```
sip_bin:/usr/bin/sip
```

But on the system, there is no such `sip` file:

```
ll /usr/bin | grep -i sip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 947 oct 24  2015 dh_sip3*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 868 jan 18  2016 dh_sip*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 59K mai 16 17:00 lsipc*
```

There is a `sip` folder `/usr/share` but no executable.

By trying to run `sip`:

```
$ sip -V
The program 'sip' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: 
sudo apt install sip-dev
```

So.... install it:

```
$ apt-get install sip-dev
```

Check it's there:

```
$ sip -V
4.17
$ ll /usr/bin/ | grep sip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 947 oct 24  2015 dh_sip3*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 868 jan 18  2016 dh_sip*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 357K jan 18  2016 sip*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 59K mai 16 17:00 lsipc*
```

Yepee, `sip` is here now!

And retry the QGIS compilation...:

```
[...]
[ 99%] Building CXX object python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis__gui.dir/gui/sip_guipart0.cpp.o
[ 99%] Building CXX object python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis__gui.dir/gui/sip_guipart1.cpp.o
[ 99%] Built target translations
[ 99%] Building CXX object python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis__gui.dir/gui/sip_guipart2.cpp.o
[ 99%] Building CXX object python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis__gui.dir/gui/sip_guipart3.cpp.o
[100%] Built target staged-plugins-on-build
```

\o/ YES!

### The new issues (2x):

```
Couldn't load PyQGIS.
Python support will be disabled.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/opt/QGIS/build_master/output/python/qgis/core/__init__.py", line 27, in 
    from qgis._core import *
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtSql'


Python version:
3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

QGIS version:
3.3.0-Master 'Master', a82de83
```

To fix this one, one has to install `pyqt5.qtsql` manually (it does not seem to come along `python3-pyqt5`):

```
$ apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtsql
```

(...) Same thing for 'PyQt5.QtSvg':

```
$ apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtsvg
```

Then, QGIS finally starts normally with a nice Python console:

[image: QGIS 3 Help page]
[image: QGIS 3 Python3 console]

The two last issues were clearly due to a lack in the dependencies installation from my side.